# Where is the gnome update manager configuration files stored?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, gnome

Where are the gnome update manager configuration files located? My goal is to make a shell script that will auto-config the update manager, so that it does daily updates and what not, without using the ui. I mainly just need to know where they are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Manager stores it's settings in GConf (editable with the gconf-editor).

GConf stores preferences data in a set of configuration sources.
The sources used, their properties, and the order in which they are used by GConf is defined in the `/etc/gconf/<version>/path` file.

More info [here](https://projects.gnome.org/gconf/).